# fatal error LNK1107 when generating lib file from vlc dll

Tags: dll, vlc

I followed the instructions on this site http://wiki.videolan.org/GenerateLibFromDll for generating a lib file from a dll.  The def file is created fine and I have editted it as suggested but when I try to generate the lib file I get the LNK1107 error for an invalid or corrupt file.  Any help would be most welcome.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try another way: call function from dll by getting pointer with GetProcAddress;

Example:
[C++ calling a dll](http://goffconcepts.com/techarticles/development/cpp/calldll.html)

**Update:**

VLC media player downloaded as 7zip version;

I choose the way with GetProcAddress:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    //VLC_PUBLIC_API const char * libvlc_get_version(void);

    //Set directory path with libvlccore.dll and libvlc.dll
    SetCurrentDirectory("C:/Program Files/VideoLAN/VLC");

    HINSTANCE hGetProcIDDLL = LoadLibrary("libvlc.dll");

    FARPROC lpfnGetProcessID = GetProcAddress(HMODULE(hGetProcIDDLL),"libvlc_get_version"); 

    if(lpfnGetProcessID == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "GetProcAddress failed";

        return 1;
    }

    typedef const char * (__stdcall * pICFUNC)(void); 

    pICFUNC MyFunction = pICFUNC(lpfnGetProcessID);

    std::cout << MyFunction() << std::endl;

    //output: 1.1.4 The Luggage

    return 0;
}
```

It works fine for me, but you must change Character Set from default Unicode to Multi-Byte:
Project -> Properties -> General -> Character Set;

Try it! and good luck!;)

**Update 2:**

I got lib, here the trace from cmd:

> Microsoft Windows XP [Version
>   5.1.2600] (C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.
>
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio 9.0\VC\bin>vcvars32.bat
>
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio 9.0\VC\bin>"C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   9.0\Common7\Tools\vsvars32.bat" Setting environment for using
>   Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 x86
>   tools.
>
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio 9.0\VC\bin>dumpbin.exe /exports
>   "D:\My
>   Downloads\VLC\vlc-1.1.4-win32\vlc-1.1.4\libvlc.dll"
>
> > "C:\Documents and Settings \Eugene\My Documents\Visual Studio
> >     2008\Projects\VLCApp\VLCApp\libvlc.def"
>
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio 9.0\VC\bin>lib
>   /def:"C:\Documents and S
>   ettings\Eugene\My Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2008\Projects\VLCApp\VLCApp\libvlc.def
>   " /out:"C:\Documents and
>   Settings\Eugene\My Documents\Visual
>   Studio 2008\Project
>   s\VLCApp\VLCApp\libvlc.lib"
>   /machine:x86 Microsoft (R) Library
>   Manager Version 9.00.30729.01
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. 
>   All rights reserved.
>
> Creating library C:\Documents and
>   Settings\Eugene\My Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2008\Projects\VLCApp\VLCApp\libvlc.lib
>   and object C:\Documents and
>   Settings\Euge ne\My Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2008\Projects\VLCApp\VLCApp\libvlc.exp
>
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio 9.0\VC\bin>

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried that example but it didn't appear to work.

Comment: @paj7777 Do you know parameters of exporting functions? Is this dll yours own library or third party?)))

Comment: I have the parameters as I have the header files, the dll is part of vlc, if you follow the link I supplied that will take you to the wiki for vlc.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks for the recent post.  A call to get version is fine but when I try to call libvlc_new I get a calling convention runtime error although I'm pretty sure I'm passing the parameters correctly. Is there anyway of checking the required convention against my own?

Comment: Sorry, I tried, but I do not know how to help you, i did not work with VLC. Maybe exe-module makes some specific initializations before calling libvlc_new, like: init COM, fill some specific structs, set some variables or paths, etc; Maybe you need to check such options;)

Comment: Check this link http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/nVLC.aspx they write wrapper for .net, maybe you'll find some ideas;)

Comment: And one more thing. As I found, there are two versions of libvlc.h; If you download opensource you'll find second version of this header and definitions of some suspicious functions like system_Init; Also check libvlc.c;

Comment: I finally managed to get the lib file. It appears that if you leave space between def: and the location of the def file you a lnk1107 error.  Thanks for your help and I've learnt something about accessing external DLLs.